# Getting blogger url for dublin core tags

Tags: tags, blogger

I am trying to modify dc tags element for blogger, the tags is something like this:

```
<meta name="DC.Title" content="title" />
<meta name="DC.Creator" content="creator" />
<meta name="DC.Description" content="description" />
```

But this tags can only be applied in one page(static), if say, I have 100 pages then all of the pages will be using the same tags and hence the wrong ones.

I am trying to automatically generate the tags according to the page info and to get the meta description from the template, I am using below code:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description'/>
```

So I modify it to something like this:

```
<meta name="DC.Title" content="<data:blog.pageTitle/>" />
<meta name="DC.Description" content="data:blog.metaDescription" />
```

I am trying this, so that the tags chang automatically according to the pages, and the same tags info isn't repeated in all pages. But it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code instead -

```
<meta name="DC.Title" expr:content="data:blog.pageName" />
<meta name="DC.Description" expr:content="data:blog.metaDescription" />
```

You will notice that we have added `expr:` in front of the `content` attribute. This is needed for telling the Blogger XML parser to replace the data layout tag with its dynamic value according to the page being viewed

Answer (score 0):

This `content="<meta name="DC.Title" content="<data:blog.pageTitle/>" />"` and `<meta name="DC.Description" content="data:blog.metaDescription" />` will insert a static value for the `DC.title` tag and `DC.description` tag respectively instead of inserting a dynamic value. This is also a coding error and to fix that `expr:content` should be used.

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' name='dc.title'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='dc.description'/>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' property='dc.description'/>
</b:if>
```